# How can you prevent a TitleWindow pop-up from being drug in AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, popup

I have a class that inherits from TitleWindow, which was used as a pop-up, and which couldn't be drug.  It used to be written in MXML, so disabling its draggability (in such a way as to keep it centered) was about as simple as specifying this in its root element opening tag:

```
move="PopUpManager.centerPopUp(this);"
```

I'm rewriting it in pure AS3, and I'm having a hard time getting something like this to work.  I've tried overriding the x and y setters to call PopUpManager.centerPopUp(), I've tried overriding the startDrag() function to do the same, I've tried making startDrag() either do nothing or just call stopDrag(), etc.  This isn't working.  How do you do this?  Thanks!

Comment: The equivalent of your code in AS3 is `this.addEventListener('move', function(event):void { PopUpManager.centerPopUp(this); });`. I wonder why you're trying to make life hard though...

Comment: Come to think of it, the `this` scope in an anonymous function might not be what you'd expect. Better use a class-level function.

Comment: Looks like that did the trick, thanks.  Move that into an answer, and I'll accept it.  What do you mean about making life hard though?

Comment: He was being facetious.  Humor for the those in the know.

Comment: Well, writing it in AS instead of using MXML. Though in this case I agree that views should not be polluted with event handlers.

Comment: Sumit went ahead and submitted an answer today, it looks like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class MyTitleWindow extends TitleWindow
{
    public function MyTitleWindow()
    {
        super();
        this.addEventListener(MoveEvent.MOVE, centerTitleWindow);
    }

    private function centerTitleWindow(event:MoveEvent):void
    {
        PopUpManager.centerPopUp(this);
    }
}
```